# How can I import a table by adjusting the record IDs to the existing table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

By default, in phphmyadmin, when exporting a table, there is a string "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table name`;", which means that when importing an exported table, it will replace an existing one (i.e., it will erase the records and insert new ones).

I need to import additional data into an existing table.

But, as I said, the imported table completely replaces the existing one in the database.

And I need THE NEW TABLE TO COMPLEMENT THE "OLD" ONE.

I believe that if the "old" table has the last id=10, then the next id of the imported table will be -11.

(I import the `mysql`file)

Please tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do this:

1. rename a table that already exists in the database
2. importing a new table
3. combine with `UNION`

You know the easiest way-write